# How to write down a note that is sustained while there are other simultaneous pitches in the same bar?

Tags: piano, notation, keyboard

I'm writing down piano sheet music and I'm not sure how correctly to write a specific section. The left hand is playing a little arpeggio and I want the first note to be sustained. I came up with two ways to write it down (see below), but I'm not sure which is correct. So the question is: which is the right way to notate this? If it's the first method, I would also like to know if the starting rest is necessary?

[image: two ways to write down sustained note]

Comment: Can you play this with your left hand only? I think I injured my left hand just by looking at it! :)

Comment: @xnakos This is about as far as I can play it with one hand, but it's a fair point since the later parts might be a bit too wide even for me. Thankfully this piece is well suited for a sustain pedal, so straining a hand shouldn't be necessary. :)

Comment: @xnakos An adult should be able to play it with the left hand alone without too much difficulty, and without the aid of a pedal.

Comment: @200_success I do not have a piano nearby, but I think that, as it is and without a pedal, the G-F#-G part can only be played with the thumb jumping, which will not sound that good. I do not believe that the index finger could reach that F#. But I do not have a piano nearby and I guess I am speculating a bit.

Comment: @xnakos I would use 5-2-1-2-1-2 as the fingering.

Comment: @200_success With your pinky stuck on the lowest G (the reason this question was asked)? Different hands require different measures, that is for sure. It just seemed impossible for me, in theory. Only a piano will tell! :)

Comment: @xnakos " I do not believe that the index finger could reach that F#." - it depends how flexible your hands are as well as how big they are. Playing a 7th fingered 5-2 shouldn't be a big deal at a "professional" level. Beginners, and/or children whose hands are still growing are a different situation of course.

Comment: You have a sustained note so there is no reason to try too hard to do legato with your top note.  I would just repeatedly use my thumb when comfortable.  There's no point of trying to stretch a 7th using pinky and index if it's slower and more cumbersome than just using all pinky and thumb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first way is correct, and yes, the initial quarter rest *is* important. It might not seem important in this example, but in more complex environments these rests are vitally important.

A performer will probably know what you mean if you were to write the second measure, but it's needlessly "busy." It also doesn't clarify that it's two separate musical lines occurring, which is clearly shown in the first measure.

Comment: The essential thing is to make it clear exactly *when* to play the first D. If there are no other notes, you need to rest to indicate that. If there was some music on the top staff, or if this pattern was repeated, maybe the rest is not absolutely *essential*, but since it doesn't take up any space on the score that could be used for anything else, there is no good reason *not* to include it.

Comment: I find it easier to explain both the rest and the use of the dotted whole note as there being two voices (bass and tenor) on the same staff. In fact, were the whole note to have a stem, it would be pointing down, to distinguish this voice from the upward pointing stems of the other voice.