# What is the meaning of this notation that looks like a rest superimposed on a note?

Tags: notation, engraving, rests

In the picture below, it looks like there is a rest superimposed on top of a note. What does this mean?

[image: It looks like a rest superimposed on top of a note.]

Comment: It means "bug" or perhaps "user error."

Comment: See also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/rest-above-a-note-in-a-piano-piece

Answer (score 20):

It's a misprint. Both are 16th-note `A`s, and the rests are misplaced.

The rests should be placed lower on the page, level with the stems-down eighth note chords. They represent a separate "voice" — imagine two instruments playing: one instrument plays the upper notes, the other instrument has the rests and the lower notes.

Whatever this piece is, I highly recommend looking for a different version. This is very poorly engraved. In addition to the misplaced rests, the final note either should be an eighth note (not a sixteenth) or should not be dotted.

Here is a correct engraving:
[image: corrected OP engraving]

Comment: To be fair, I’ve seen worse.

Comment: Indeed, but Aaron's advice is nonetheless good well taken.  There's no point in struggling with a faulty edition if you can find a better one.

Comment: The stave has two parts - part 1 is sticks up, part 2 is sticks down. The rest should be there but it's in the wrong place. It should be further down the stave so it's clear that it applies to part 2

Comment: "Engraved" - if only! You don't get this kind of nonsense if you employ an engraver.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you just reinforcing my answer, or was there a previous comment that was deleted, or something else?

Comment: @Aaron - when you said "the rests shouldn't be there" I'd read that as "shouldn't appear on the page _at all_". But on re-reading, I think you must have meant they shouldn't be _there_ on the page; they should be _somewhere else_ on the page instead. I misunderstood, I think.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS Good point. I've clarified. I just figured you hadn't read beyond the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Could be part of a separate voice. Upward stemmed notes are voice 1 and downward ones are a voice 2. The rests are then correct, albeit positioned very poorly. This is possible in some score writing programs.

Answer (score 1):

That is an error. It belongs to the second voice, with the 8ths with stems down, and should be moved lower.