# How do you play dotted eighth notes in bar 35 with bass clef?

Tags: piano

[image]

This piece is called Hotel California.
This is the link

EDIT: sorry for the unclear explanation; I meant the dotted eighth notes at bar 35.

Comment: Does this help: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/15929/70803

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rest above a note in a piano piece](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/rest-above-a-note-in-a-piano-piece) -- also have a look at the many questions linked to that one.

Comment: If written out correctly, a vertical ruler will show exactly when each note gets played.

Comment: I thought perhaps you were asking about how to count the dotted 8th notes. Others have guessed your question is about the rest. Voting to close as unclear; I’ll be happy to retract if you edit to explain more (and it’s not a duplicate)

Comment: The highlighter bar shows measure 36, not 35. The beaming in bar 35 is a bit unhelpful, to interpret the rhythm... is the rhythm in bar 35 what you're asking about?

Comment: I meant bar 35 and yes i was asking abt how to play dotted eight notes tgt with left hand.

Comment: @AndyBonner Comment to you, since you mentioned retracting your vote. I've voted to reopen. OP clarified the question is about timing, which is not a duplicate. (The duplicate, by the way, is about handling multiple voices, although the title mentions dealing with a rest.)

Comment: Essentially this is a problem of horribly bad notation. Instead of this https://petzel.at/d1.png this should be notated somewhat like this https://petzel.at/d2.png .

Comment: So, everyone piles on to quickly close, now the question is answerable, but we have to wait for people to hopefully come back and re-open... how about asking the OP to clarify and give them some time to update the question.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis (Counterpoint, hold back on the closure, and people pile on answers that aren't actually what the OP's looking for. In this case it was a dup so nobody jumped in to explain the rest, but I've seen a lot of "I'm not sure whether this is what you mean but if so ___" answers lately. I dunno, the reopening takes time, yes, but IMO it's net-better.)

Comment: The question is closed and idk what to do

Comment: Don't worry, it just needs one more vote to re-open. But the quickest answer is "This is a miserable notation job"; I recommend starting by buying an actual published transcription. For the right hand, know that a dotted 8th equals three 16ths, and that might help count it out. The left hand is just plain wrong.

Comment: A quick image search shows that many versions transcribe those right-hand notes as quarter-note triplets, like in m 39. Listening to the original, what's shown here is more accurate, but could be notated more clearly. But if it helps, just call them three equal notes.

Answer (score 6):

I think a visual should explain it all...

[image]

The two hands sometimes coincide rhythmically other times one hand plays before the other.

I numbered the sequence of those events in red numbers. When both hands play at the same time you can call it a *rhythmic unison*, and in those moments you will see the sequence number is simultaneously on both the left and right hand notes. When the hands are not in rhythmic unison, one comes before the other, and those get separate sequence numbers.

- `1` happens before the rhythmic unison of `2`
- `3` comes before the rhythmic unison of `4`
- `5` comes before `6` which comes before `7` before a rhythmic unison at `8`

Those sequence numbers would not be the common way to count time in `4/4` meter, so below I put the metrical counting using syllables like `1 ee and a 2...`. This happens to be the *composite rhythm*, which is the combination of all rhythmic events from all parts. Notice how on beat 3 the count is `3 and a`, and the `and` is in the left hand while the `a` is in the right hand. The metrical counting puts all those events together into a composite rhythm.

Beyond just dropping another music theory term, awareness of composite rhythm can help your rhythm training. Try actually counting it out loud , while playing, and feel the hands split up the composite rhythm, and where each hand coincides with the count.

You could write out the count with `LH/RH` placement like this...

[image]

...even away from the keyboard you can turn that into a hand/finger tapping exercise.

Finally, notice the issue about the poor notation. Especially in the right hand, third to fourth beat. Beaming those two beats separately and then using a tie makes the *synocaption* much easier to read.

Comment: 6 and 8 are supposed to be E, not F#, right?

Comment: @BobRodes, thanks for spotting that! now fixed. "poor notation" indeed!

Comment: Looks like something a computer algorithm came up with. :)

Answer (score 3):

The measure is poorly notated, because it doesn't clearly show the boundaries of the individual beats. It would be better notated as shown below.

[image: Renotated example]

Specifically, the second dotted eighth should be a sixteenth tied to an eighth. Also, the adjacent Es in the left hand are played simultaneously.

The following image shows the alignment of the notes.

[image: Alignment example]

Comment: Might help the OP to draw some lines showing how some of these notes are simultaneous and some aren't. (I tried just now, but unfortunately the offset dotted-quarter C creates some confusion.) Might have been a smarter arrangement to skip that dotted quarter. It gets high marks for, assumedly, trying to very meticulously recreate exactly what the guitar does, but there are many simplified versions that a beginner might find easier.

Comment: @AndyBonner Good thought. Done! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I’ve already pointed out in a comment this is a case of bad notation. The notation

[image]

is quite hard to understand, in fact the most natural reading would give this 5 beats instead of 4. It would be much better to notate this like this

[image]

If you then still have problems aligning the notes you can even do

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I understand now